# Node: Load/read the content of a page from external website(domain)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have my personal webpage hosted in a sever which does not have Node.

I have my server-side script running on Node Server (Heroku).

I am trying to read the content of my personal page from my server js file...

Here is the server code

**server.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


fs.readFile("http://myportfolio.maxxweb.com", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Loaded personal page")
    }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/main.html");

});

app.get("/api/names", (req, res) => {
    console.log("names api call... ");
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/error.html')

});

app.get("/get-portfolio-page-content", (req, res) => {

    var options = {
        host: 'http://myportfolio.maxxweb.com'
    };

    http.get(options, function(http_res) {
        // initialize the container for our data
        var data = "";

        // this event fires many times, each time collecting another piece of the response
        http_res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            // append this chunk to our growing `data` var
            data += chunk;
        });

        // this event fires *one* time, after all the `data` events/chunks have been gathered
        http_res.on("end", function() {
            // you can use res.send instead of console.log to output via express
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at port ` + port);
})
```

Before deplyoing code to Heroku, I run the command> **node server.js** from my local.
I get the following error:

```
Server running at port 3000
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\maxxpc\project\heroku\http:\myportfolio.maxxweb.com']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   'C:\\maxxpc\\project\\heroku\\http:\\myportfolio.maxxweb.com' }
```

I am new to Node environment. Someone please guide me.

Comment: gotta check out the docs. the first bit you have won't work: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_url_object_support

> For most fs module functions, the path or filename argument may be passed as a WHATWG URL object. Only URL objects using the `file:` protocol are supported.

Answer (score 3):

The `fs` module is for interacting with the file system, not for making HTTP requests.

You need to use a module designed for making HTTP requests such as axios or the built-in http and https modules.

Comment: thanks. Using axios.get() I am now able to grab the entire html content as a big heap of junk inside my .then() function call... But how to make any sense of this data? I want to send a particular block of this DOM back to the browser like this. app.get("/get-portfolio-page-content", (request, response) => { axios.get("").then(data => response.send(block-of-my-DOM))  });

Comment: Find a library for processing HTML with.

Comment: I think only if i send the content back to browser, it will be recognized as a proper html DOM. Or is there a way to understand the html markup inside server.js file

Comment: You use an HTML parser on the server.